# I am having trouble finding a command that shows what version of samba is installed on my RPi3

Tags: samba, packages

I am running Raspbian jessie 8 on my RPi3. I am trying to see what version of samba is installed if any. I do not remember installing it as far as i know it is for remote access but I am not totally sure. It seems like when I update I see it updating but again i am not 100% sure. Can some one give me a hint on the command. I have already tried uname -a, smbd -v, and smbdstatus.

Comment: For now I am going to move on from this question. I do not have a clear understanding of Samba and I ask the question before I  understood what I actually needed. Thanks for the help I will comeback to this at a later date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be installed by default.

The command to use is `apt-cache policy samba`

E.g. on my Pi3

```
$ apt-cache policy samba
samba:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u5
  Version table:
     2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u5 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to just type `smbd -V` if you want a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use it I don't know why you care.

Rather than a specific answer you can use a command like the following to find installed packages, which will generally give you a version.

```
dpkg-query -l | grep samba
```

shows on my system

```
ii  python-samba                          2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u6                    armhf        Python bindings for Samba
ii  samba-common                          2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u6                    all          common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  samba-common-bin                      2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u6                    armhf        Samba common files used by both the server and the client
ii  samba-libs:armhf                      2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u6                    armhf        Samba core libraries
```

Comment: I read on FossBites to check what version of samba you are running as you nay need apply a patch  for certain versions due to  wannacry. I am still learning so it could have been something I installed or I might not have. I would rather be safe than sorry. Responsible and continually learning that is why I care..thanks for stepping down off your pedestal to answer after I accepted an answer and left a comment of the result.

Comment: @Pismurf I find you comment incomprehensible, although I presume the intent is pejorative, which is not the spirit of Stack Exchange. You do not understand the nature of the site; it takes some time to write an answer, and someone else may post an answer in this time. I still believe `samba` is installed, as the output I posted indicates (although I do not use it myself0. `dpkg-query -L samba-common` will show the samba related files on your system.

Comment: I apologize I miss judged your response..I understand the nature of the site I interpreted what you wrote and reacted emotionally. I read what you wrote again and I apologize for my response again. Can you or will you tell help me understand this? If I did not install it  why does | grep show that  are other packages using it but when it says it has not been installed? (You can point me to reading material rather than typing it out.) Would this mean that I should apply the patch or is that even relevant if all my packages are up to date and upgraded?

Comment: @Pismurf I cannot explain the output of `apt-cache policy`, I have only been using Linux for 15 years, and much is still a mystery. `apt-cache policy dhcpcd` also shows `Installed: (none)` although most of us use it on a daily basis. I presume this applies to packages included in the original image. I have certainly never installed samba.